# Proving the Lower Triangle Inequality

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I need help verifying my attempted proof of the lower triangle inequality which states that

\begin{align}
\text{Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$}
\end{align}

I used is the theorem which states that

\begin{align}
\text{Let $a \geq 0$.$|x| \leq a$ iff $-a \leq x \leq a$ where $x,a \in \mathbb{R}$}
\end{align}

The following is the proof

---

Let $x,y$ be real numbers, $|x| - |y| \leq |x-y|$

*Proof.* In case $x = y = 0$,

\begin{align}
 0 = 0
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

In case that $x = 0$ and $y$ is a non-zero real number,

\begin{align}
-(-y) < -y \text{ for $y<0$};\\
-(-y) = -(-y) \text{ for $y>0$}
\end{align}

establishing the result for the case.

In case that $x$ is a non-zero and $y=0$

\begin{align}
-x = -x \text{ for $x<0$};\\
 x = x \text{ for $x>0$}
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

In case that $x,y$ are non-zero and $x>y$,

\begin{align}
x-y = x-y &\text{ for $x,y>0$};\\
x-(-y) < x-y &\text{ for $x>0$, $y<0$, and $|x|<|y|$ (the $LHS$ is negative)};\\
x-(-y) < x-y &\text{ for $x>0$, $y<0$, and $|x|>|y|$ (the $LHS$ is positive)};\\
(-x)-(-y) < |x-y| &\text{ for $x,y<0$ (the $LHS$ is negative)}
\end{align}

establishing the results for this case.

In case that $x,y$ are non-zero and $x<y$,

\begin{align}
x-y < |x-y| &\text{ for $x,y>0$ (the $LHS$ is negative)};\\
(-x)-y < |x-y| &\text{ for $x<0$, $y>0$, and $|x|<|y|$ (the $LHS$ is negative)};\\
(-x)-y < |x-y| &\text{ for $x<0$, $y>0$, and $|x|>|y|$ (the $LHS$ is positive)};\\
(-x)-(-y) = |x-y| &\text{ for $x,y<0$}
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

Since the result for each possible cases has been established, $|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$.

Let $x,y$ be real numbers, $|x| - |y| \geq -|x-y|$

*Proof.* In case $x = y = 0$,

\begin{align}
 0 = 0
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

In case that $x = 0$ and $y$ is a non-zero real number,

\begin{align}
-|y| \geq -|-y|\\
\text{Because $|-y| = |-1||y| = |y|$}\\
-|y| = -|y|
\end{align}
establishing the result for the case.

In case that $x$ is a non-zero and $y=0$

\begin{align}
|x| \geq -|x|
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

In case that $x,y$ are non-zero and $x>y$,

\begin{align}
x-y > -|x-y| &\text{ for $x,y>0$};\\
(x)-(-y) > -|x-y| &\text{ for $x>0$, $y<0$, and $|x|<|y|$ (the $LHS$ is negative)};\\
(x)-(-y) > -|x-y| &\text{ for $x>0$, $y<0$, and $|x|>|y|$ (the $LHS$ is positive)};\\
(-x)-(-y) = -|x-y| &\text{ for $x,y<0$}
\end{align}

establishing the results for this case.

In case that $x,y$ are non-zero and $x<y$,

\begin{align}
x-y = -|x-y| &\text{ for $x,y>0$};\\
(-x)-y > -|x-y| &\text{ for $x<0$, $y>0$, and $|x|<|y|$ (the $LHS$ is negative)};\\
(-x)-y > -|x-y| &\text{ for $x<0$, $y>0$, and $|x|>|y|$ (the $LHS$ is positive)};\\
(-x)-(-y) > -|x-y| &\text{ for $x,y<0$}
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

Since the result for each possible cases has been established, $|x|-|y| \geq -|x-y|$.

Because $-|x-y| \leq |x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$, by the theorem in the beginning of this post, $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$

---

I think my attempted proof is a conjecture rather than a proof.

---

**Reference**

Daepp, U. and Gorkin, P., 2011. *Reading, Writing, and Proving*. 2nd ed. pp. 55.

Comment: Oh good lord this is way longer than it needs to be. Start here: $|x| = |x-y+y| \le |x-y| +|y|$.

Comment: Or use the triangle inequality on $\lvert x \rvert = \lvert x - y + y \rvert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

On one hand, we have that

\begin{align*}
|x| = |(x - y) + y| \leq |x - y| + |y| \Rightarrow |x - y| \geq |x| - |y|
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
|y| = |(y - x) + x| \leq |y - x| + |x| \Rightarrow |x -y | \geq |y| - |x|
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, it results that
\begin{align*}
|x - y| \geq \max\{|x| - |y|,-(|x| - |y|)\} = ||x| - |y||
\end{align*}

and we are done.